# UPROPERTY error in Unreal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, unreal-engine4

I am following an Unreal tutorial called 'Battery Pickup' and I think the version the tutorial was made on was an old one. I have the exact Code as in the tutorial, they don't have any errors and yet I am getting all these syntax errors in my editor and I don't really know how to get rid of them.

This is my Code:

```
#pragma once
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Pickup.generated.h"
UCLASS()
class BATTERYCOLLECTOR_API APickup : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public: 
    APickup();
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;
    virtual void Tick( float DeltaSeconds ) override;
    FORCEINLINE class UStaticMeshComponent* GetMesh() const { return PickupMesh; }

private:
    UProperty(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "**Pickup**", meta = (**AllowPrivateAccess** = "true")**)**
    class UStaticMeshComponent* **PickupMesh**; 
};
```

These are the errors I get (Text in bold in the above Code):
Identifier AllowPrivateAccess is undefined C++ Unreal,
Identifier PickupMesh is undefined,
Not suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char[7]" to "UPROPERTY",
Some other brackets missing errors.

[Here is what it looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiVwy.png)

Comment: The tutorial says "UPROPERTY", not "UProperty".

Comment: That worked!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Although the comment is a valid answer, I try to provide some more information.

The macro used by Unreal to identify classes, properties, etc., are all in capital case like UCLASS(), UPROPERTY(). Documentation is here [[1]](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Reference/index.html).

And specifically for UPROPERTY(), documentation is here [[2]](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Reference/Properties/index.html). Escpecially read the "Property Specifiers" section, the property can be decorated/controlled by these specifiers, so that you can expose it to Blueprint, control how it can be edited in editor, etc.

UCLASS(), USTRUCT(), UFUNCTION() and UPARAM() all has its own specifiers sets, if you want to develop Unreal Engine games using C++ then you must also read them. If you can't be sure how the specifier works then just search it in UE's engine source code. The full engine source code is really a luck for Unreal developers.